# Duke University Library Logo

Tags: graphics

I am not sure if this question is within the scope of this community, but I am rather dumbfounded by the logo of Duke University Libraries, which can be found near the bottom left corner of its [homepage](http://library.duke.edu/).

[image]

To me, this looks like the profile of a much-despised Biblical figure, whom I doubt is subject the figure is really portraying. Who, or what, then, is the image portraying?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about academia. Also see [Why a Blue Devil? The Story of the Duke Mascot](http://library.duke.edu/rubenstein/uarchives/history/articles/bluedevil).

Comment: Thanks for the link @ff524. I'm happy to close the question myself, but not sure if I can do so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duke University's sports mascot is the "Blue Devil"  The library's logo references this mascot.